# Asymptotic Analysis of code that are unusual

Tags: asymptotics

We all know that the RUN Time of most of our program are Big O of linear time, quadratic time, cubic time or log time. But Can this be in unusual or uncommon poly time like $x^6-y$ or cosine function time ?

Comment: What are the $x$ and $y$  in $x^6-y$? And cosine is $O(1)$ since $cos(x)\le 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (lets ignore the fact that it can also be negative)

Comment: $x^6 -y$ is an algebraic identity. the cosine thing is a trigonometry function

Comment: Thats not what I asked about. Clearly, that much I already know. I asked what would you think $x$ and $y$ represent? And also I made a remark about that cosine runtime being $O(1)$ anyways (you can't do better than $O(1)$).

Comment: For any time-constructible function $f(n)$ there exists an algorithm running in time $O(f(n))$, namely the one which simply prints out the binary representation of $f(n)$.

Comment: @nirshahar the $x$ and $y$ belongs to the real number set

Comment: (Like [en.wikipedia on trigonometric functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)? Really?)

Comment: The question about $x$ and $y$ was not about their domain. It was about their *role* in `Asymptotic Analysis of code` after a mention of `Big O`, which conventionally uses a single variable $n (\in  \mathbb{N})$ to characterise problem size: everything else needs to be introduced.